# Getting System.InvalidOperationException when uploading a hex file to an arduino board using ArduinoUploader Library

Tags: c#, wpf, hex, arduino-uno

I am using `ArduinoUploader` package to upload a hex file to my arduino board from my WPF App

```
private void MenuItem_Mode_Oscilloscope(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
   var uploader = new ArduinoSketchUploader(

   new ArduinoSketchUploaderOptions()
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Users\thinkhigh\Desktop\StandardFirmata.ino.hex",
       //PortName = "COM3",
        ArduinoModel = ArduinoUploader.Hardware.ArduinoModel.UnoR3
    });
            
    //FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(FileName);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    uploader.UploadSketch();
}
```

But i am getting this error while running this

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains more than one
> element'

What is the issue and how do i solve this?

Comment: An exception is always thrown at a particular line of code. Please show the exact line that throws the exception. Also refer to the API documentation. It will usually explain the potential exceptions that are being thrown by a member. Maybe your configuration is wrong. Double-check the file path. *"Sequence contains more than one element"* - This appears to be related to a collection. But there is no  collection in your posted code. Again, it would be helpful if you post the code and its context of the line that trows.

Answer (score -1):

Its working now in the documentation it was said it auto detects port if not specified, i tried specifying the port where the arduino is connected and now it works fine